How can i fix that code inside my angular component?
I'm using Taiga UI to create a component for a project in Angular. When I try to reuse a button component with a DropDownElement, the button is not be displayed and the console displays the following error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')
There is the code where I insert the component:
<tui-badge>Test</tui-badge>
 </span>
    <hr />
    <button
        iconStart="@tui.bell"
        tuiIconButton
        type="button"
    >
        Notifications
        <tui-badge-notification />
    </button>
    <app-user-avatar-dropdown></app-user-avatar-dropdown>
</header>

And the TS code is:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { KeyValuePipe, NgForOf} from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import { tuiAsPortal, TuiPortals, TuiRepeatTimes} from '@taiga-ui/cdk';
import {
    TuiAppearance,
    TuiButton,
    TuiDataList,
    TuiDropdown,
    TuiDropdownService,
    TuiIcon,
    TuiTitle,
} from '@taiga-ui/core';
import {
    TuiAvatar,
    TuiBadge,
    TuiBadgeNotification,
    TuiChevron,
    TuiDataListDropdownManager,
    TuiFade,
    TuiSwitch,
    TuiTabs,
} from '@taiga-ui/kit';
import { TuiCardLarge, TuiHeader, TuiNavigation} from '@taiga-ui/layout';  
import { UserAvatarDropdownComponent } from '../../shop/components/user-avatar-dropdown/user-avatar-dropdown.component';

const ICON =""; // not very important right?

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    KeyValuePipe,
    NgForOf,
    RouterLink,
    RouterLinkActive,
    RouterOutlet,
    TuiAppearance,
    TuiAvatar,
    TuiBadge,
    TuiBadgeNotification,
    TuiButton,
    TuiCardLarge,
    TuiChevron,
    TuiDataList,
    TuiDataListDropdownManager,
    TuiDropdown,
    TuiFade,
    TuiHeader,
    TuiIcon,
    TuiNavigation,
    TuiRepeatTimes,
    TuiSwitch,
    TuiTabs,
    TuiTitle,
    UserAvatarDropdownComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrl: './layout.component.css',
  providers: [TuiDropdownService, tuiAsPortal(TuiDropdownService)],
})

export class LayoutComponent extends TuiPortals {
  protected expanded = false;
    protected open = false;
    protected switch = false;
    //protected readonly routes = DemoRoute;
 
    protected readonly drawer = {
        Components: [
            {name: 'Button', icon: ICON},
            {name: 'Input', icon: ICON},
            {name: 'Tooltip', icon: ICON},
        ],
        Essentials: [
            {name: 'Getting started', icon: ICON},
            {name: 'Showcase', icon: ICON},
            {name: 'Typography', icon: ICON},
        ],
    };
}

And here is the code of the button that doesn't work properly:
@if (profile()) {
<button
  appearance="flat"
  tuiButton
  type="button"
  [tuiAppearanceState]="open ? 'hover' : null"
  [tuiDropdown]="content"
  [(tuiDropdownOpen)]="open"
>
  {{ profile() }}
</button>
} @else {
<button
  appearance="flat"
  iconStart="@tui.user"
  tuiIconButton
  type="button"
  [tuiAppearanceState]="open ? 'hover' : null"
  [tuiDropdown]="content"
  [(tuiDropdownOpen)]="open"
></button>
}

<ng-template #content>
  <tui-data-list>
    @if (profile()) {
    <button tuiOption [routerLink]="['/shop/account']">
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-items-start">
        <tui-icon icon="@tui.user-pen" class="mr-2" />
        Profile
      </div>
    </button>

    <button tuiOption (click)="logout()">
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-items-start">
        <tui-icon icon="@tui.log-out" class="mr-2" />
        Log out
      </div>
    </button>

    } @else {
    <button tuiOption (click)="showDialog()">
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-items-start">
        <tui-icon icon="@tui.log-in" class="mr-2" />
        Sign In
      </div>
    </button>
    }
  </tui-data-list>
</ng-template>

import { Component, computed, inject, INJECTOR, Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TuiDataListDropdownManager } from '@taiga-ui/kit';
import {
  TuiButton,
  TuiDataList,
  TuiDialogService,
  TuiDropdown,
  TuiIcon,
  TuiIconPipe,
  TuiOption,
} from '@taiga-ui/core';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthModalComponent } from '../auth-modal/auth-modal.component';
import { UserMeService } from '../../features/users/user-me.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../features/auth/auth.service';
import { PolymorpheusComponent } from '@taiga-ui/polymorpheus';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-avatar-dropdown',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TuiButton,
    TuiDropdown,
    TuiDataListDropdownManager,
    TuiDataList,
    TuiOption,
    TuiIcon,
    TuiIconPipe,
    RouterLink,
    AuthModalComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './user-avatar-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrl: './user-avatar-dropdown.component.css',
})
export class UserAvatarDropdownComponent {
  private readonly dialogs: TuiDialogService = inject(TuiDialogService);
  private readonly injector = inject(INJECTOR);
  private readonly userMeService: UserMeService = inject(UserMeService);
  private readonly authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);

  // Whether the dropdown is open
  protected open = false;
  protected dropdownOpen = false;

  // Stores the user's profile whether it is logged in or not
  profile: Signal<string | null> = computed(() => {
    const user = this.userMeService.state.asReadonly()();

    if (Object.keys(user).length !== 0)
      return `${user.firstName[0]}${user.familyName[0]}`;
    else return null;
  });

  /**
   * The dialog to show when the user clicks on the "Sign In/Up" button
   */
  private readonly dialog = this.dialogs.open<boolean>(
    new PolymorpheusComponent(AuthModalComponent, this.injector),
    {
      dismissible: true,
      label: 'Join the party!',
    },
  );

  /**
   * Opens the dropdown
   */
  showDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.subscribe();
  }

  /**
   * Logs the user out
   */
  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.open = false;
      },
    });
  }
}

It's like two hours that I'm try different solution, without result. So the question is: How can I make the user button work properly??
